# Urban Heat Islands in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am working to create Urban Heat Islands effect in Google Earth Engine. But there is a problem  with function BT - images.addBands is not a function

```
var images = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_TOA")
               .filterDate('2021-01-01', '2022-01-01')
               .filterBounds(city);

var vizParams = {
  bands: ['B5', 'B4', 'B3'],
  min: 0,
  max: 0.4,
};
               
Map.addLayer(images, vizParams);
Map.addLayer(city);

function NDVI(image) {
  
  var nir = image.select('B5');
  var red = image.select('B4');
   var ndvi = nir.subtract(red).divide(nir.add(red)).rename('NDVI');
    return image.addBands(ndvi);
}

var images1= images.map(NDVI);

function TOA(image) {
  
  var toa = image.select('B10').multiply(0.0003342).add(0.1).rename('TOA');
  
  return image.addBands(toa);
}
var images2= images1.map(TOA);

function BT(image) {
  
  var bt = image.expression(
    '1321.0789/ln((774.8853/toa)+1))-273.15',
    {'toa': image.select('TOA')}
    ).rename('BT');
  return images.addBands(bt);
}

var images3= images2.map(BT);


function PVI(image) {
  
  var ndvi1 = image.select('NDVI').subtract(image.select('NDVI').min());
  var ndvi2 = ee.Image.constant(image.select('NDVI').max()).subtract(image.select('NDVI').min());
  var pvi = ndvi1.divide(ndvi2).pow(2).rename('PVI'); 
  return image.addBands(pvi);
}

var images4= images3.map(PVI);


function Error(image)  {
  
  var e=ee.Image.constant(0.004).multiply(image.select('PVI')).add(0.986).rename('Error');
  
  return image.addBands(pvi);
  
}

var images5= images4.map(Error);

function LST (image) {
  
  lst1 = ee.Image.constant(0.00115).multiply(image.select('BT')).divide(1.4388);
  lst2 = ee.Image.constant(1).add(lst1).multiply(image.select('Error'));
  lst3 = image.select('BT').divide(lst2).rename('LST');
  
  return image.addBands(lst3);
  
}
var images6= images5.map(Error);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is produced because you are returning "images" instead image. However, when this is fixed, there are other problems in your code. As you don't put the formula for calculating PVI, I'm assuming that you're pretending to calculate min and max values in city area for each image. So, your approach is wrong. You should use 'reduceRegion' method instead. Formula for calculating BT also has issues. However, after fixing them, LST values have not sense.

There is another issue in error function. You need to return image named e; not pvi.

So, your code fixed for an arbitrary area in Las Vegas city (Nevada, USA), looks as follows.

```
var city = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-115.32969970703125, 36.28475226999499],
          [-115.32969970703125, 36.01417965979669],
          [-115.01109619140625, 36.01417965979669],
          [-115.01109619140625, 36.28475226999499]]], null, false);

Map.centerObject(city);

var images = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_TOA")
               .filterDate('2021-01-01', '2022-01-01')
               .filterBounds(city);

print(images.first().select('B5').projection().nominalScale());

var vizParams = {
  bands: ['B5', 'B4', 'B3'],
  min: 0,
  max: 0.4,
};
               
Map.addLayer(images, vizParams);
Map.addLayer(city);

function NDVI(image) {
  
  var nir = image.select('B5');
  var red = image.select('B4');
   var ndvi = nir.subtract(red).divide(nir.add(red)).rename('NDVI');
    return image.addBands(ndvi);
}

var images1= images.map(NDVI);

function TOA(image) {
  
  var toa = image.select('B10').multiply(0.0003342).add(0.1).rename('TOA');
  
  return image.addBands(toa);
}

var images2= images1.map(TOA);

function BT(image) {
  
  var bt = image.expression(
    '1321.0789/log((774.8853/toa)+1)-273.15',
    {'toa': image.select('TOA')}
    ).rename('BT');

  return image.addBands(bt);

  
}

var images3= images2.map(BT);

function PVI(image) {
  
  var min = ee.Number(ee.Image(image.select('NDVI')).reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.min(), city, 30).get('NDVI'));
  var max = ee.Number(ee.Image(image.select('NDVI')).reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.max(), city, 30).get('NDVI'));
  
  var ndvi1 = image.select('NDVI').subtract(min);
  var ndvi2 = ee.Image.constant(max).subtract(min);
  var pvi = ndvi1.divide(ndvi2).pow(2).rename('PVI'); 
  
  return image.addBands(pvi);

}

var images4 = images3.map(PVI);

//Map.addLayer(images4, {}, 'images4')

function Error(image)  {
  
  var e = ee.Image.constant(0.004).multiply(image.select('PVI')).add(0.986).rename('Error');
  
  return image.addBands(e);
  
}

var images5 = images4.map(Error);

function LST (image) {
  
  lst1 = ee.Image.constant(0.00115).multiply(image.select('BT')).divide(1.4388);
  lst2 = ee.Image.constant(1).add(lst1).multiply(image.select('Error'));
  lst3 = image.select('BT').divide(lst2).rename('LST');
  
  return image.addBands(lst3);
  
}
var images6= images5.map(Error);
```

After running above [code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/e2c9d165ff5eebbbe32595338050b340) in GEE code editor, I got following result without any error. However, values for some bands don't have any sense.

[image]

Comment: There was a mistake in the last line var images6= images5.map(Error); =var images6= images5.map(LST);

Comment: Now the error is LST: Tile error: Error in map- "Image.constant: Parameter 'value' is required"